# amChart Javascript not showing up Unless Window Size Change

Tags: javascript, html, css, amcharts

I cannot get the "where" part working on this website. The map only shows up once the user resizes the window. I've tried for a few weeks trying to fix the problem and I simply do not understand what I can do. I've found other problems people had where within hidden div's the amchart won't work... But doing an initialize or show often fixes that, but not for me.

Any Ideas?

http://spshulem.com/indexlatest.html

The code in question:

```
<div class="pf">
    <div class="pf__item pf__item_collapsed">
        <div class="pf__trigger pf__trigger_collapsed">
            <span class="pf__trigger-text pf__trigger-text_collapsed" id="where">Where</span>
            <span class="pf__trigger-text pf__trigger-text_expanded"><span id="where">Where</span><span id="seen"> You've Seen Me.</span></span>
        </div>

        <div class="pf__full">
            <div class="pf__reducer">
                <p>While my hometown resides in Santa Barbara, California, I worked closely with over 10 startups in 5 months in San Francisco this year. I'm also a huge fan of travel, and have visited 18% of the world and counting so far .</p>

              <script type="text/javascript">
              // svg path for target icon
              var targetSVG = "M9,0C4.029,0,0,4.029,0,9s4.029,9,9,9s9-4.029,9-9S13.971,0,9,0z M9,15.93 c-3.83,0-6.93-3.1-6.93-6.93S5.17,2.07,9,2.07s6.93,3.1,6.93,6.93S12.83,15.93,9,15.93 M12.5,9c0,1.933-1.567,3.5-3.5,3.5S5.5,10.933,5.5,9S7.067,5.5,9,5.5 S12.5,7.067,12.5,9z";

              var map = AmCharts.makeChart("mapdiv", {
                type: "map",
                pathToImages: "map/ammap/images/",

                imagesSettings: {
                    rollOverColor: "#CC0000",
                    rollOverScale: 3,
                    selectedScale: 3,
                    selectedColor: "#CC0000"
                },

                dataProvider: {
                    map: "worldLow",
                    images: [{
                        svgPath: targetSVG,
                        zoomLevel: 5,
                        scale: 0.3,
                        title: "Argentina",
                        latitude: -35.2092,
                        longitude: -65.3728
                    }, {
                        svgPath: targetSVG,
                        zoomLevel: 5,
                        scale: 0.3,
                        title: "Antarctica",
                        latitude: -59.9678,
                        longitude: -60.5766
                    }, {

                    ]
                },

                objectList: {
                    container: "listdiv"
                },
                showImagesInList: true
              });

                      </script>


                  <div>
                      <div id="listdiv" style="width:200px; overflow:auto; height:500px; float:right; background-color:#FFF;"></div>
                      <div id="mapdiv" style="margin-right:200px; background-color:#FFF; height: 500px;"></div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: Ensure your container is shown after you call any validation method, btw. could you reup your sample?

Comment: http://spshulem.com/indexlatestold.html ... I've tried writing the chart again, even initializing it, and nothing. It only shows when I change window size in the browser.